# How to add Scringo sdk to Android Studio

Tags: android, sdk, android-studio, scringo

I want to use scringo in my app, I am registered and i have added my app in the scringo web, i also downloaded the sdk but i do not know how to add the sdk in android studio to use it.. I search in google but i only see two questions here but no great answers..

I tried to copy the files to the "libs" folder but with no result.. i also see the scringo web (http://www.scringo.com/docs/android-guides/quickstart/) but is only for eclipse..

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add a library project to the Android Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract scringo.2.5.6.jar.

On Android Studio go to **File > Project Stucture**. Click on the "+" button and select **Import .JAR**. Choose the extracted .Jar and you're good to go